# Burndown chart starts from today and not the iteration start date

Tags: azure-devops, devops, burndowncharts

I have uploaded workitems to Azure DevOps and specified iteration start date /finish date with burndown on count of workitems.

I am plotting burndown by day but the burndown in Azure starts from the day the workitems were uploaded. Is there a way to generate the burndown from the iteration start date

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the sprint burndown chart (**Sprints** unders **Boards** --> **Analytics** tab).
It starts from the start date of the selected iteration by default. And it allows to configure the start date and end date of the burndown chart. Check below document for more information.

[Configure and monitor sprint burndown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=remaining-work%2Cmay)

If you want to add a burndown widget to your Dashboards. There are Burndown or Sprint Burndown widgets you can use. Check below document for more information.

[Configure a Burndown or Burnup widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked at the knowledge base but since all work items are imported as of todays date the burn down chart starts as of today rather than the iteration start date configured, which is in the past. I have managed to find a solution. Simply create the work items with the dates when the iteration actually started and the burndown will generate from iteration start date

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Create the work items with the dates when the iteration actually started and the burndown will generate from iteration start date instead of current date.